# JSON_Extract from list of json string

Tags: sql, presto, json-extract

I want to extract some values for particular keys from a table with json string as below.

| raw_data | ... |
| --- | --- |
| {"label": "XXX", "lines":[{"amount":1000, "category": "A"}, {"amount":100, "category": "B"}, {"amount":10, "category": "C"}]} | ... |

I am expecting an outcome like

| label | amount | category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| XXX | [1000, 100, 10] | ['A', 'B', 'C'] |

I am using the following sql query to achieve that

```
select 
JSON_EXTRACT(raw_data, '$.lines[*].amount') AS amount,
JSON_EXTRACT(raw_data, '$.lines[*].category') AS category,
JSON_EXTRACT(raw_data, '$.label') AS label
from table
```

I can get a specific element of the list with `[0]` , `[1]` etc.  But the sql code doesn't work with `[*]`. I am getting the following error
`Invalid JSON path: '$.lines[*].amount'`

**Edit**

I am using Presto

Comment: Mysql/Maria please add the platform.

Comment: What system are you using? Mariadb/Mysql or Presto? They have very different behavior for that function.

Comment: I am using Presto

Comment: Presto can extract scalar value only. https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/json.html Iterate over your JSON, extract separate values then combine them to arrays back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Json path support in Presto is very limited, so you need to do some processing manually for example with casts and [array functions](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#transform):

```sql
-- sample data
with dataset (raw_data) as (
    values '{"label": "XXX", "lines":[{"amount":1000, "category": "A"}, {"amount":100, "category": "B"}, {"amount":10, "category": "C"}]}'
)

-- query
select label,
    transform(lines, l -> l['amount']) amount,
    transform(lines, l -> l['category']) category
from (
    select JSON_EXTRACT(raw_data, '$.label') AS label,
        cast(JSON_EXTRACT(raw_data, '$.lines') as array(map(varchar, json))) lines
    from dataset
);
```

Output:

| label | amount | category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| XXX | [1000, 100, 10] | ["A", "B", "C"] |

In [Trino](https://trino.io/blog/2020/12/27/announcing-trino.html) json path support was [vastly improved](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/json.html#id6), so you can do next:

```sql
-- query
select JSON_EXTRACT(raw_data, '$.label') label,
       JSON_QUERY(raw_data, 'lax $.lines[*].amount' WITH ARRAY WRAPPER) amount,
       JSON_QUERY(raw_data, 'lax $.lines[*].category' WITH ARRAY WRAPPER) category
from dataset;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `json_table` and `json_arrayagg`:

```
select json_extract(t.raw_data, '$.label'),
  (select json_arrayagg(t1.v) from json_table(t.raw_data, '$.lines[*]' columns (v int path '$.amount')) t1),
  (select json_arrayagg(t1.v) from json_table(t.raw_data, '$.lines[*]' columns (v text path '$.category')) t1)
from tbl t
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the expected output using `unnest` to flatten and `array_agg` to aggregate in `Presto`. Below is the SQL used and output generated:

```
WITH dataset AS (
  SELECT
    * from sf_73535794
)
SELECT raw_data.label,array_agg(t.lines.amount) as amount,array_agg(t.lines.category) as category FROM dataset
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(raw_data.lines) as t(lines) group by 1
```

Output:

[image]